# data from database echoed with htmlentities gives weird signs in hebrew

Tags: php, mysql

After I fetch data from database I want to place it on page using `htmlentities`.
But the problem is that when I echo it out displays weird characters in the output - squares and other weird signs. I have checked and its because I echo in Hebrew. Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `house_data` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";
        while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query))){
        $types[] = $row;
}
foreach($types as $data){
   echo htmlentities($data['city']);
}
```

Comment: did you try specifying a character set and see if that works: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ?

Comment: From the PHP Manual page: Like htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards. Although this argument is technically optional, you are highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code.

Comment: In addition to what others have said above, does your page have a `charset` meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Maximus2012 said, the problem is in the third argument which is encoding, VERY IMPORTANT NOTICE: an encoding in the beggining of the page does not append on this kind of cases. so just add the encoding and it works like a charm:

```
echo htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8");
```